# Mysql cache for SELECT...IN

Tags: mysql, caching

Is "`SELECT * FROM PRODUCT where Id in (.. iDList..)`" with iDList changed partially cached by MySQL?

As the query is executed thousand of times per minute, it would be helpful if MySQL can cache those rows.

Sorry if my question is dumb..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately mysql's query cache [caches complete queries only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html), which are only retrieved if exactly the same query is submitted.

> The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again.

Mysql query cache will not help you in this particular case.

Comment: That's sad news... by the way , I am using php query cache http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php , is it redundant when mysql is also caching the query ?

Comment: I do not know this product well enough to say. But I'm not sure if this product invalidates cache entries if any underlying table is changed.